# Using SELECT clause in ELSE part of SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.

Table number 1 (`Lab_test`): with integer columns named `labtest_id` (pk) and `project_no`. Second table (`Project`) has two columns, first column named `project_id` (int) and second column `project_name` (string). Also I have two parameters which are passed to the query.

I have to make a query which will extract `labtest_id` and `proj_num`. `proj_num` have to be obtained in following way: if `Lab_test.project_no` is not null, take this value, else go to referencing table `Project` and take `project_name`.

I tried with bunch of combinations using SQL CASE IF-THEN-ELSE statements, but no luck:

```
    SELECT lab.labtest_id, proj_num, 
    FROM Lab_test lab 
                (CASE 
                    WHEN lab.project_no IS NOT NULL THEN lab.project_no 
                    ELSE (SELECT proj.project_name 
                          FROM Project proj 
                          WHERE proj.project_id = lab.project_no) 
                          ) AS proj_num 
            WHERE lab.status = 'DONE' AND lab.user_id = 436
```

Comment: provide some sample data and your desired output in tabular format

Comment: Please clean up your question tags. `mysql` conflicts with Microsoft `sql-server`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `left join` and `coalesce()` to replace the case when expression that you've used to check null

```
SELECT lab.labtest_id, coalesce(lab.project_no,proj.project_name) as proj_num
FROM Lab_test lab 
left join Project proj on proj.p,roject_id = lab.project_no
where lab.status = 'DONE' AND lab.user_id = 436
```

Comment: Damn, thanks Fahmi, didn't know about, this coalesce function. As soon as my boss confirms, I'll tick your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

> if Lab_test.project_no is not null, take this value, else go to referencing table Project and take project_name.

I don't believe you.  I think you have the logic backwards -- use the referenced table if it is available.  Otherwise use the number.

That would suggest:

```
SELECT l.labtest_id, COALESCE(p.project_name, l.project_no) as proj_num
FROM Lab_test l LEFT JOIN
     Project p 
     ON p.p,roject_id = l.project_no
WHERE l.status = 'DONE' AND l.user_id = 436;
```

If the `project_no` is a *number*, then you might have a type conversion problem.  If that is an issue:

```
SELECT l.labtest_id,
       COALESCE(p.project_name, CAST(l.project_no as CHAR)) as proj_num
FROM Lab_test l LEFT JOIN
     Project p 
     ON p.p,roject_id = l.project_no
WHERE l.status = 'DONE' AND l.user_id = 436;
```

Comment: I think it is okay how Fahmi did it. If project_no is not null (i.e. it is a number) I will take that value. if project_no is null, use project_id in a Left join clause and extract project_name from project? Btw, I am getting these columns from Spring Boot (@SqlResultSetMapping), and for that proj_num col I set it to expect String, so whatever it comes out, it should be a string

Comment: @Miljan . . . If `projecct_no` is `null` there is no matching row.

Comment: If I understand my boss, if project_no is null, project_id will definitely be not null. Reverse also apply.